# Write a program in python to find the sum of the first 200 jumpy numbers

Tags: python, numbers

I just started learning python and I have a task to submit as homework. 
I have to write a program that prints out the sum of the first 200 jumpy numbers.
Jumpy numbers are numbers whose digits are neither increasing nor decreasing. for example 101, 102, 103, 104.... unlike increasing numbers such as 2347, 378, 459 and decreasing numbers 975, 854, 741.
From the little I know, I have written this, but i cant figure out how to do the rest. Please help...

```
#python program to find the sum of first 200 jumpy numbers
minimum = int(input(" Please Enter the Minimum Value : "))
maximum = int(input(" Please Enter the Maximum Value : "))
total = 0

for number in range(minimum, maximum+1):
    if(number[2] == 1):

       print("{0}".format(number))
       total = total + number

print("The Sum of Jumpy Numbers from {0} to {1} = {2}".format(minimum, number, total))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gokul's answer is very nice, however if you aren't a professional coder (me too), then I wrote this simpler version, however much longer.

```
#python program to find the sum of first 200 jumpy numbers
minimum = int(input(" Please Enter the Minimum Value : "))
maximum = int(input(" Please Enter the Maximum Value : "))
total = 0

def isJumpy(x):
    increasing, decreasing = True,True
    x = [int(x) for x in str(x)]
    x = list(map(int,x))
    for n in range(len(x)-1):
        if int(x[n]) > int(x[n+1]):
            pass
        else:
            increasing = False
        if int(x[n]) < int(x[n+1]):
            pass
        else:
            decreasing = False

    if increasing == False or decreasing == False:
        return True
    else:
        return False






for i in range(minimum,maximum+1):
    if isJumpy(i):
        total += i

print("The Sum of Jumpy Numbers from {0} to {1} = {2}".format(minimum, maximum, total))
```

If you have any questions, or the code is wrong please let me know. Btw this was a fun little challenge :)

Comment: Thanks , yours too is elaborate and nice

Comment: Good luck with your class!

Comment: Thanks guys. This has been really helpful.

Comment: I observed that The code prints the sum from a set minimum to 500. 
How can I make it sum up the first 500 jumpy numbers. Because there is no way to know the maximum. I suppose I have to use a count function.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by sum from a set minimum to 500: if minimum = 0 and maximum = 1000 i get jumpy numbers over 500, however if you want to sum up the first 500 jump numbers, there is no need for an input, and you can simply set a jumpynumbercount, and increase that every time isJumpy(i) == True. If you need anymore help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
min = 1
max = 100
f=lambda n,i=1:n and-~f(n-g(i),i+1)
g=lambda i:i<10or i%100%11%9==g(i/10)>0
values = [i for i in range(min,max) if g(i)]
print values
print sum(values)
```

g(i) checks for jumping number or not

Use your custom min and max. lambda functions are used for smaller expressions.

```
lambda arguments : expression
```

sum() is inbuilt function of python.

Took help from [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/180693/jumping-numbers/180715#180715)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I think our definition of jumpy numbers are different. 
Jumpy numbers in this case have their digits not increasing or reducing. for exampl
101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,120, 121,  are jumpy numbers. the numbers 110,111,112,113 are not jumpy numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def is_jumpy (n):
   num_list = [int (x) for x in str (n)]
   goes_up = goes_down = False
   for index in range (1, len (num_list)):
      if (num_list[index-1] < num_list[index]):
         goes_up = True
      elif (num_list[index-1] > num_list[index]):
         goes_down = True
      if (goes_up and goes_down):
         return True
   return False

sum=0
for i in range (min,max):
   if (is_bouncy (i)):
      sum += i
print(f'the sum of the jumpy numbers between{min} and {max} is {sum}')
```